# Java char is represented by unsigned integer

Tags: java, types

I came across the phrase that Java char type is represented as a 16-bit unsigned integer. I thought that the sign is just how a compiler or interpreter treats the data, but the OS and hardware make no distinction. And in this case it should be treated is as a character, not a number. So what is the meaning of saying it's represented as an unsigned integer?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html could help understand

Comment: It means exactly what it says, and what you said about the compiler and the interpreter, and the OS has exactly nothing to do with it.

Comment: @EJP So is it misleading to say it's represented by an unsigned integer? The Oracle doc linked above makes no such mention.

Comment: Well, it's certainly reflected in what happens when you convert it to an `int`, or do math with it...

Comment: @allstar What on earth is misleading about it? What are you talking about? What's your question? NB The Oracle tutorial clearly states that the minimum value is zero and the maximum is `\uffff`. That's an unsigned range.

Comment: I think Louis answered the question. If you do math with it, it is treated as an unsigned integer. Otherwise, it's just 16 bits treated as UTF-16.

Comment: I still have no idea what you're actually asking here.

Comment: I do not understand what makes 0 to ffff by definition an unsigned range. A range of values can be interpreted as either signed or unsigned, correct? For example, a short is 16-bit signed, and those bits are in the same range 0 to ffff. What Louis explained is that when Java interprets a char as a numeric type, it interprets it as unsigned.

Comment: If it was a signed range it would be `\u8fff` to `\u7fff`, i.e. -32768 to 32767. It is unsigned, so it starts at zero, not at a negative number, and it goes all the way to FFFF instead of stopping at 7FFF. What Louis explained is perfectly correct, don't misunderstand me, but you also said exactly the same thing in your question. What I don't understand here is what you don't understand, when you've answered your own question.

Comment: OK I might be seeing what you're saying, and I appreciate the patience. In signed and unsigned integers, the full range of binary values between 0000 and FFFF are used. But with signed integers, the ordering (from -32768 to 32767) is an ordering from 8FFF to 7FFF. It was unclear to me is what significance 'ordering' has to chars - there's no inherent order that characters have. But when you treat them as numbers, make comparisons, etc, then a numeric representation is meaningful, and their representation is as an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the hardware does make a distinction between signed and unsigned values.  For example, if you take a look at Intel instruction sets you will see that are different instructions for signed multiplication and division, and for unsigned multiplication and division.  And they give different answers for the same (bit-for-bit) inputs.

Now for the Java case of `char`.

It is true that `char` is unsigned in Java, but ... surprisingly ... it doesn't require special support for unsigned arithmetic.

The Java Language Specification states that when you perform arithmetic, bitwise, shift and comparison operations on `byte`, `short` and `char`, the operands are first promoted to `int` (or `long`, `float` or `double` if required).  The operation is then performed using 32-bit signed (or whatever) instructions and produces a 32-bit (or whatever) result.  For example:

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';
char something = a + b;           // error!
char something1 = (char)(a + b);  // ok
```

---

> So what is the meaning of saying it's represented as an unsigned integer?

Well, basically, it >>is<< an unsigned number.  The values for `char` are 0 through 65535.  They are all greater or equal to zero.

When the `char` values are converted to `int` to perform operations on them, the conversion is as you would expect; char 0 converts to int 0, 65535 goes to 65535 and all of the others in between.

Answer (score 0):

It means that, when converting to `int` or `long`, the value will be unsigned, so the most significant bit being set won't cause the `int` or `long` to end up negative through sign extension.

Comment: It also affects how shift operators work, and comparisons.